# Select display adapter in D3D9

Tags: c++, directx9

I have a notebook that has 2 graphics card one Intel and one nvidia graphics cards.
When I want to start my game I right click on the exe file and select run with graphics processor->Nvidia but my engine stills run with my Intel graphics card on d3d9. 
Is there any way to choose the graphics card with code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following page includes a link to a PDF from NVIDIA outlining procedures for how to ensure that the NVIDIA adapter is always selected: https://developer.nvidia.com/optimus